# How to save stream from api as file?

Tags: c#, file

I'm trying to download files from an api. I'll recieve the filename and the file as a string looking like this:

[image]

I've playing with this but without success. The files that I've managed to create gets corrupted.
What is this and how do I convert this to a file using c#?

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve].  [Edit] your post to include information about the API you are calling and the code used to call it.  File corruption has many causes.  Given the information you've provided, it's impossible to even guess at what could be wrong.

Comment: Streams are really, under the hood, a collection of bytes, whereas strings are an 'interpretation' of those bytes into something to display.  If you are downloading a text file, then it's not quite as complicated, but if you are downloading a binary (such as a zip or mp3), then you cannot download as a string.   Also, POST SOME CODE !

Comment: Also, please post text, not images of text.  The image you posted is useless.

Comment: You are getting a 64 bit string which take file and converts to ASCII printable characters.  So you uneed to use : byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(string);  Once you get bytes you can then apply encoding to get string : string output = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);

Comment: @jdweng thank you. That was what I was missing. Works now. Have a nice day